# Point inside a rational triangle

Tags: geometry

Does there exist such a point in a rational triangle (meaning that all 3 sides are rational), which forms lines of rational length with all 3 vertices and thus makes 3 new rational triangles inside the base triangle (that means dragon eye figure is needed)? How to find this point if it exists? Is there any special point, i.e. TCP (Triangle Center Point) or formula?

Comment: What have you tried? It helps to show your efforts so that people don't just dismiss the question or downvote, as well as showing potential answerers what has already been done.

Comment: See J.H.J. Almering, [Rational Quadrilaterals](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82540042.pdf).  In particular, the first Theorem.

Comment: Right now I have no ideas, I just ask for advice, maybe the problem has already been solved by someone.

Comment: Eric Towers, thanks.